# OSX xdebug and relation to PEAR

Tags: php, pear, xdebug, pecl, acquia

I have the Acquia Drupal stack 7.4.4 - which is using PHP 5.2.17 installed on an OSX 10.6.8

**Drupal's PHP Stack:**

User [~/]> php -v
PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Jun 30 2011 12:12:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans

**OS X's PHP Stack:**

User [~/]> /usr/bin/php -v
PHP 5.3.4 (cli) (built: Dec 15 2010 12:15:07) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

As seen the Xdebug binary for PHP 5.2 downloaded from http://code.activestate.com/komodo/remotedebugging/ is correctly loaded with PHP 5.2.17 This is also verified with phpinfo.

The purpose for my questions is to reach a stage where I can compile the xdebug.so for the Acquia Drupal stack to be used with NetBeans 7.

So - which version of PEAR / PECL is the correct one to have installed on my system, the one for PHP 5.2.17 or the one for 5.3.4 - or does it not matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a different .so for 5.2 and 5.3 as they have incompatible APIs. A "PEAR/PECL" version makes little sense as Xdebug only uses PEAR as the installer. Just make sure you have a PHP 5.2 and a PHP 5.3 Xdebug.so. The Komodo download provides both.

Answer (score 0):

Great - "Xdebug only uses PEAR as the installer" - I had, with my limited experience, been wondering if those libraries were also used within xdebug/Acquia/NetBeans while actually debugging the code. So PEAR/PECL's sole pupose is now clarified, and it also remains clear that xdebug needs to be compiled for PHP 5.2 as that is the PHP version used by the Acquia 7.4.4 stack.

Now relying on Komodo binaries, without knowing how they were derived and why they do actually work, or even worse - why my own compilations does not work - that is a possible short cut and it does work for me for the time being.

**but**

... neither Xdebug, Drupal, Acquia or Netbeans provides an up to date description on how to compile the xdebug on a Mac for these tools used on a OS X 10.6.8 (64-bit intel). I assume a simple but up to date and clear step-by-step-guide e.g. as bullet points would benefit a lot of developers-want-to-be ... any takers?